# Is it possible to use a variable and not specify a return type in postgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Consider this T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @ColorID INT
SET @ColorID = 3

SELECT *, left(name,3) 
FROM Products p
WHERE ColorID = @ColorID
```

This works but doesn't declare a variable:

```
SELECT *, substring(name,1,3) 
FROM Products p
WHERE ColorID = 3
```

I tried this:

```
DO $$
DECLARE ColorID INT;
BEGIN
    ColorID := 3;

    SELECT *, substring(name,1,3) 
    FROM Products p
    WHERE ColorID = ColorID 
END$$;
```

It wants me to specify the result set. I don't want to do that because it keeps changing as I'm just exploring the data.

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
```

I tried "return query" but then get this error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use RETURN QUERY in a non-SETOF function
```

So I want to return multiple rows without specifying what the result set should look like. Using PostgreSQL 9.4.4

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? Some clients offer variables "outside" of SQL.

Comment: pgAdmin III and Postgres Enterprise Manager v5 (still researching) - I used a temp table for results and that worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anonymous code block ([`DO` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html)) cannot return rows and Postgres has no global variables.
There are few ways to live without it. Four of them are as follows.

Use common table expression ([`WITH` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html))

```
WITH def AS (
    SELECT 3 AS colorid
    )
SELECT *, substring(name,1,3) 
FROM products
JOIN def
USING (colorid);
```

Use a temporary table for variables:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE var(colorid int);
INSERT INTO var values (3);
SELECT *, substring(name,1,3) 
FROM products
JOIN var
USING (colorid);
DROP TABLE var;
```

Use a temporary table for results:

```
DO $$
DECLARE v_colorid INT;
BEGIN
    v_colorid := 3;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE res AS 
        SELECT *, substring(name,1,3) 
        FROM products
        WHERE colorid = v_colorid;
END $$;
SELECT * 
FROM res;
DROP TABLE res;
```

Create a function (example):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION select_from_products()
RETURNS TABLE (colorid int, name text, abbr text)
LANGUAGE plpgsql as $$
DECLARE v_colorid INT;
BEGIN
    v_colorid := 3;
    RETURN QUERY
        SELECT *, substring(p.name,1,3) 
        FROM products p
        WHERE p.colorid = v_colorid;
END $$;

SELECT * FROM select_from_products();
```