# Is it possible to declare variables in PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to run a query in a PostgreSQL client (Postico) and an experiencing nothing but frustration for what I assumed would be a fairly straightforward task, as it is in T-SQL.

My declarations are as follows:

```
DECLARE vYOU varchar := 'LD', 
vSOME_ID int := '9999', 
vSOME_THING varchar := 'ABCD.0.1.2', 
vSOME_THING2 varchar := 'ABCD.0.0.2', 
vSTART_DATE date := '2016-08-23', 
vEND_DATE date := '2016-08-24';
```

The variables are prepended with 'v' and are of course referenced at various points throughout the remainder of my query.

However, this gives me the following error:

```
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: syntax error at or near "varchar"
```

I have Googled in vain, checking my datatypes and the general syntax and tried multiple iterations of this, though admittedly I'm not sure about whether I have listed the declared variables correctly. In any case I see various different answers about whether this can or can't be done in PostgreSQL.

Would love a definitive answer as to where I'm going wrong or whether this is even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish it did, but no, not really...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652477/how-to-perform-a-select-query-in-a-do-block

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to define global variables in postgresql](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31316053/1995738) and [Is it possible to use a variable and not specify a return type in postgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34143571/1995738).

Comment: Thanks both. This makes it seem like it's possible, no?
https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/declare_vars.php

Comment: Within the context of a function, yes.  If you want to go through the effort to build a function (that can return a query), then sure, this is quite possible.  My impression was you wanted more of a stand-alone query that incorporates variables.  If you want an example of the function that returns a query, that is quite doable

Comment: @Hambone you're absolutely right, I was indeed referring to a standalone query. I have no desire at all to build a function to return this query. I didn't realise the page I linked to pertained to function creation specifically, that's not really clear.

Comment: Maybe creating temporary table with keys, values and querying it using subqueries or CTE's is acceptable solution?