# How to get a output of a variable from function in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am new to PostgreSQL. I have the query:

```
---------
DO
$$
DECLARE
    l_pin INT;
    l_pin1 int;
BEGIN
    l_pin := 3;
    l_pin1 := 4;

select l_pin,l_pin1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
--------------------------
```

from above query am getting an error as

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 9 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

I need to get the values of `l_pin` and `l_pin1` as output.

Comment: Why did you tag sql server and a specific version of sql server when you are not using sql server at all?

Comment: See: [Is it possible to use a variable and not specify a return type in postgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34142802/1995738)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there is a [`DO` statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html), not a "query" nor a "function". `DO` statements cannot return anything at all.

- [How to perform a select query in a DO block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652477/how-to-perform-a-select-query-in-a-do-block/14653151#14653151)

The displayed error is because you cannot call `SELECT` in a plpgsql code block without assigning the result. To actually *return* values from a plpgsql function, use some form of [`RETURN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) (explicitly or implicitly).
As minimal example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo(OUT l_pin int, OUT l_pin1 int)
  RETURNS record AS  -- RETURNS record is optional because of OUT parameters
$func$
BEGIN
   l_pin := 3;
   l_pin1 := 4;

   RETURN;  -- RETURN is optional here because of OUT parameters
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM foo();
```

Related:

- [Can I make a plpgsql function return an integer without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8169676/can-i-make-a-plpgsql-function-return-an-integer-without-using-a-variable/8169928#8169928)
- [SELECT or PERFORM in a PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10115806/postgresql-function-perform/10117015#10117015)
- [Returning from a function with OUT parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762734/returning-from-a-function-with-out-parameter/20763195#20763195)

Answer (score 0):

First you can create a new type that can hold multiple values:

```
CREATE TYPE type_name AS (l_pin INTEGER, l_pin1 INTEGER);
```

Then you can do something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name()
RETURNS type_name AS $$
  DECLARE
    result type_name;
  BEGIN
    /* Code that puts those values into type_name object 
    i.e. 
    result.l_pin := 3;
    result.l_pin1 := 4;
    */ 
    return result ;
  END
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: It could be done without creating additional type but using `OUT` parameters: `CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name(OUT l_pin INTEGER, OUT l_pin1 INTEGER) AS $$ ...`. For example: `create function foo (out x int, out y int) language sql as $$ select 1, 2 $$;`

Comment: @Abelisto You certainly can if you're on version 8.1+, but for me I prefer the creation of a type because it makes the code cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: Creating a type for this seems excessive. (And who would still be running Postgres older than version 8.1 - released in 2005?)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  It was for the sake of completeness, how does pointing out the version requirements for a feature hurt anything?  Also, downvoting a correct answer because you think one line of code is excessive is poor form.

Comment: @BShaps: Granted, your answer works. So I removed the downvote. It's still bad advice IMO. And it's misleading to claim we'd *need* to create a new type.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I appreciate the feedback and I'll edit the language of my answer to reflect that my approach is not the only way.  IMO it is good advice, especially if you start dealing with functions that need to return a lot of values, but you're entitled to disagree.